# Entity Framework DateTime has millisecond difference while data persists in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I am saving DateTime in table and then querying using the same DateTime object in where clause which results `null`. I have noticed a difference in Milliseconds between C# DateTime Object and Date Stored in the database.

**Note:** Limitation is that for some reason I have to use DateTime to retrieve the record.

Following is the C# Code used to save and then retrieve the same record.

```
                DateTime startTime= DateTime.Now;

                // startTime Object Details 
                //Date                {9/9/2020 12:00:00 AM}
                //Day                 8 
                //DayOfWeek           Tuesday
                //DayOfYear           252
                //Hour                13 
                //Kind                Local
                //Millisecond         221
                //Minute              40
                //Month               9
                //Second              30
                //Year                2020
                
                BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION bjeToAdd = new BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION();
                bjeToAdd.JOB_NAME = "POPULATE_TRAN_SUMMARY";
                bjeToAdd.START_TIME = startTime;
                
                context.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.Add(bjeToAdd);
                context.SaveChanges();
```

At this point data is saved in the database. On querying the database using SQL `SELECT * FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` the value `START_TIME` column is `2020-09-08 13:40:30.223`. Notice the difference in millisecond `221` and `223`. Now the C# code continues as follows:

```
                // startTime object is not changed millisecond of this startTime Object is 221 !! 
                var bjeToUpdate = (from batch in context.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION
                           where batch.START_TIME == startTime
                           select batch).FirstOrDefault();
                
               // bjeToUpdate is null
```

The following are some queries along with their behavior in comments:

```
SELECT * FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE START_TIME = '2020-09-08 13:40:30.225' // No record found
SELECT * FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE START_TIME = '2020-09-08 13:40:30.224' // Record Found. START_TIME is 2020-09-08 13:40:30.223
SELECT * FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE START_TIME = '2020-09-08 13:40:30.223' // Record Found. START_TIME is 2020-09-08 13:40:30.223
SELECT * FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE START_TIME = '2020-09-08 13:40:30.222' // Record Found. START_TIME is 2020-09-08 13:40:30.223
SELECT * FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE START_TIME = '2020-09-08 13:40:30.221' // No record Found
```

Now by observing this strange behavior I want to know the following

1. Why There is a difference between milliseconds in C# DateTime Object intended to save and Database Field.
2. Observing the SQL queries why SQL has this behavior to fetch records having a difference of 001 milliseconds.

Comment: If you need that kind of precision, maybe use `datetime2` instead of `datetime` data type.

Comment: A duplicate question I believe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784110/entity-framework-losing-sql-datetime-precision

Comment: You should always use `datetime2` instead of `datetime` anyway, even if you *don't* need precision. `datetime` stores dates as a float whose integral part is the offset from 1899-12-30 and fractional part represents the time of day. WIth `datetime2` on the other hand you can specify the precision you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs for `datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#datetime-description):

> Accuracy: Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

If you really need that level of accuracy, you can use the `datetime2` data type instead. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#datetime2-description) say:

> Accuracy: 100 nanoseconds

Comment: Even if no milliseconds are needed, `datetime2(0)` would be preferable

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Agreed, my answer should probably have been more explicit about that

Comment: @DavidG thanks a lot. I tried and tested this several times and it works. changed my table field data type to datetime2.